# Mysql connection fails on java.sql.SQLException: No database selected

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection

in my application i am creating connection through the JDBC driver with such URL

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?connectionCollation=latin1_general_cs&user=user&password=password!
```

So no db is specified in the url. Then my applicaiton creates the db and i am trying to force my connection to use this DB by using the:

```
connection.setCatalog(databaseName);
```

But then the statement execution fails on:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No database selected
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2531)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setCatalog(ConnectionImpl.java:4934)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:824)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:742)
    at org.fist.DB.connection.MySQLDatabaseConnection.executeSqlFile(MySQLDatabaseConnection.java:80)
    at org.fist.products.ssc.actions.InstallSSC.recreateDatabaseAndTables(InstallSSC.java:748)
    at org.fist.products.ssc.actions.InstallSSC.execute(InstallSSC.java:263)
    at com.mercury.mtf.core.AbstractAction.run(AbstractAction.java:51)
    at com.mercury.mtf.core.Unit.runUnitAction(Unit.java:277)
    at com.mercury.mtf.core.Unit.executeUnitAction(Unit.java:144)
    at com.mercury.mtf.core.Unit.run(Unit.java:99)
    at com.mercury.mtf.core.execution.DefaultUnitExecutor.call(DefaultUnitExecutor.java:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Works for me actually.
Could you provide your code and point on line where exception is thrown?

Comment: Looks like i have found where my problem is. I am defining Statement st = connection.createStatement() before i am forcing my connection to use catalog, So my statement doesnt know about the changes and thats why it is failing on "No database selected"

Comment: That is correct: a statement created before a catalog change should not be affected by the catalog change. In other words: either you need to specify the database name in your connection URL, or issue the `setCatalog` before creating statements.